# Julia: How to filter an array with a function that needs more than 1 parameter?

Tags: lambda, filter, julia

```
filter(isodd, [1,2,3])
```

`isodd` only needs one parameter, so that's fine.
But what if I the function I want to filter the array with needs two parameters? I want the first parameter to be the changing value from the array and the second parameter to be fixed. How do I do that? Or am I obliged to use lambda?

**N.B.** The second is fixed but it's not a constant. It may change next time I filter.

Comment: I would probably use lambda functions, as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to use a closure `f = c->filter(x->x>c, [1,2,3])` or if the function is more complicated:

```
g(c,a) = filter(a) do x
           # complicated body
           x > c
         end
```

This trick is commonly used when working with some packages such as [ForwardDiff.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiff/ForwardDiff.jl).